# ArcGIS Pro Split 'multiple buffer ring' output into separate polygons based on centroids

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, buffer, splitting

I have created multiple buffer rings around 10 separate points, every 20 m for 320 m. I ran this tool with the dissolve option off.

The output is creating one polygon for every ring distance (ie every 20m ring is combined into one polygon). Is there a way to split these?

I need a separate polygon for every 20m ring around every point. In other words, instead of 1 polygon for every 20m buffer, I need 10 polygons for every 20m buffer, each with their own unique IDs.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Multipart to Singlepart would achieve what you want:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/multipart-to-singlepart.htm